# Inserting HTML image element using jinja2/flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a png image that I am trying to insert into a jinja2 template in a flask project. In my view functions I have:

```
@login_required
@main.route('/render_png')
def render_png():

bart_path=basedir+"/bart.png"

data_uri = base64.b64encode(open(bart_path, 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(data_uri)
session['job'] = img_tag

return redirect('dash')
```

my dashboard template has:

```
div id="job">{{ session['job'] or 'No value' |safe }}</div>
```

I thought using the safe filter would stop the element from being escaped. But instead in the middle of the template I see:

[image]

How can I get this working?

Comment: Could you format your question first? Indent is broken.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `bart.png` and ensured that its a proper image (and not a screenful of 'img_tag' text)?